# Compiled numpy with ICC+MKL, not passing the full test

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, debian, icc, intel-mkl

I am using Intel C++ Compiler and Intel MKL to compile numpy 1.8.1 on Debian 7.5. The Intel stuff are from [Intel® Parallel Studio XE 2013 SP1 for Linux Update 3](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-parallel-studio-xe-2013-sp1-for-linux-update-3). The `site.cfg` is roughly the same as in the [Intel tutorial](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/numpyscipy-with-intel-mkl), which is

```
[DEFAULT]
library_dirs = /usr/local/lib:/opt/intel/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64
include_dirs = /usr/local/include

[mkl]
library_dirs = /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/
include_dirs = /opt/intel/mkl/include/
mkl_libs = mkl_rt
lapack_libs =

[amd]
amd_libs = amd

[umfpack]
umfpack_libs = umfpack

[fftw]
libraries = fftw3
```

The change to `intelccompiler.py` was made in the class `IntelEM64TCCompiler`:

```
self.cc_exe = 'icc -m64 -fPIC -O3 -g -fp-model strict \
                   -fomit-frame-pointer -openmp -xhost -DMKL_ILP64'
```

and the change to `fcompiler/intel.py` was made in the class `IntelEM64TFCompiler`:

```
def get_flags_opt(self):
    return ['-i8 -xhost -openmp -fp-model strict']
```

The building command is

```
python3 setup.py config --compiler=intelem \
                 build_clib --compiler=intelem \
                 build_ext --compiler=intelem \
                 install
```

Additionally, I've added

```
source /opt/intel/bin/iccvars.sh intel64
source /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64 ilp64
```

to `.bashrc`.

The compilation went well, and the configuration printed by `numpy.show_config()` is:

```
lapack_opt_info:
    library_dirs = ['/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/']
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/opt/intel/mkl/include/']
openblas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_opt_info:
    library_dirs = ['/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/']
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/opt/intel/mkl/include/']
lapack_mkl_info:
    library_dirs = ['/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/']
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/opt/intel/mkl/include/']
mkl_info:
    library_dirs = ['/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/']
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/opt/intel/mkl/include/']
blas_mkl_info:
    library_dirs = ['/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/']
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/opt/intel/mkl/include/']
```

But when executing `numpy.test('full',verbose=10)`, it halted and reported that

```
test_assumed_shape.TestAssumedShapeSumExample.test_all ... Segmentation fault
```

Any ideas to pass this test? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `-O2` instead of `-O3`? I think I have read about issues with `-O3`.

Comment: @Bort Same issue, same place